# Apache Camel route doesn't call Processor

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-camel

I  am trying to code my first Project with Apache Camel and Spring Boot. It should call a Rest-Endpoint and process the Data but my processor is never called. What am I doing wrong here?

The logs show that the route is started and that it consumes from "direct://httpRoute". But in the End there are no logs which indicates that MyProcessor is called.

**TssImportApplication.java**

```
package de.importer.TssImport;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TssImportApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TssImportApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**MyRoute.java**

```
package de.importer.TssImport.routes;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        log.error("TEST");
        from("direct:httpRoute").to("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").process(new MyProcessor());
    }

    class MyProcessor implements Processor {

        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            log.error("TEST 2");
            System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.importer</groupId>
    <artifactId>TssImport</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TssImport</name>
    <description>Project to import data</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-log-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**LOG**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-15 17:47:54.590  INFO 30161 --- [           main] de.importer.TssImport.TssImportApplication   : Starting TssImportApplication on importer-VirtualBox with PID 30161 (/home/importer/Documents/TssImport/tssimport/target/classes started by importer in /home/importer/Documents/TssImport/tssimport)
2020-06-15 17:47:54.593  INFO 30161 --- [           main] de.importer.TssImport.TssImportApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-15 17:47:55.732  INFO 30161 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-06-15 17:47:55.912  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.apache.camel.support.LRUCacheFactory   : Detected and using LRUCacheFactory: camel-caffeine-lrucache
2020-06-15 17:47:56.437 ERROR 30161 --- [           main] de.importer.TssImport.routes.MyRoute         : TEST
2020-06-15 17:47:56.494  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootRoutesCollector   : Loading additional Camel XML routes from: classpath:camel/*.xml
2020-06-15 17:47:56.495  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootRoutesCollector   : Loading additional Camel XML rests from: classpath:camel-rest/*.xml
2020-06-15 17:47:56.886  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.camel.component.http.HttpComponent   : Created ClientConnectionManager org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager@77bb0ab5
2020-06-15 17:47:56.918  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
2020-06-15 17:47:56.919  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
2020-06-15 17:47:57.037  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Route: route1 started and consuming from: direct://httpRoute
2020-06-15 17:47:57.046  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2020-06-15 17:47:57.047  INFO 30161 --- [           main] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 0.128 seconds
2020-06-15 17:47:57.052  INFO 30161 --- [           main] de.importer.TssImport.TssImportApplication   : Started TssImportApplication in 2.989 seconds (JVM running for 3.806)
2020-06-15 17:47:57.060  WARN 30161 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : CamelContext has only been running for less than a second. If you intend to run Camel for a longer time then you can set the property camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true in application.properties or add spring-boot-starter-web JAR to the classpath.
2020-06-15 17:47:57.061  INFO 30161 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutting down
2020-06-15 17:47:57.066  INFO 30161 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 45 seconds)
2020-06-15 17:47:57.073  INFO 30161 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Route: route1 shutdown complete, was consuming from: direct://httpRoute
2020-06-15 17:47:57.074  INFO 30161 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
2020-06-15 17:47:57.081  INFO 30161 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) uptime 0.163 seconds
2020-06-15 17:47:57.081  INFO 30161 --- [extShutdownHook] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 3.3.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) is shutdown in 0.020 seconds

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you application will shutdown very quickly.
To keep the main thread blocked so that Camel stays up, either include the spring-boot-starter-web dependency, or add `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` to your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CAMEL/Spring+Boot

But still there will be no processor logs because you are not sending any messages to the `direct:httpRoute` so the processor is not invoked.

Since you can't send any message to `direct:httpRoute` from outside the vm, you will need something like below to send a message

Here I am adding a rest controller and when you go to `send-message-to-direct-channel` endpoint in browser, it will send a message to your camel route. This will require `spring-boot-starter-web` as you are adding rest controller

```
@RestController
public class DirectChannelController {
  
  @Autowired
  CamelContext camelContext;
  
  @Autowired
  ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/send-message-to-direct-channel")
  public void startCamel() {
      producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:httpRoute", "An example message everytime");
  }
}
```

or you can try

```
@Component
public class MyRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;
    
    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate producerTemp;


   @Override
   public void run(String... args) throws 
                         Exception {
   producerTemp.sendBody("direct:direct:httpRoute",
               "An example message everytime");
   }
}
```

Or try adding the following route to your configure method if you want to trigger it via timer

```
from("timer://simpleTimer?period=2000")
   .setBody()
   .simple("This is a test message")
      .to("direct:httpRoute");
```

Add `camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true` to keep the application up

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you say there is no way to call an RestService on StartUp. Or maybe scheduled?

Comment: Shouldn't "from("Timer://simpleTimer?Period=100")" invoke the Rest-Call and the Processor? Or am I missunderstanding something here?

Comment: Hm, I tried the timer earlier but it didn't work. Maybe I had a mistake. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you for your replies :)

Comment: Yes I copied it to my configure()-Method. It worked fine, thank you very much. There is one thing I changed: Instead of adding a new route I set the timer on the specific route itself.